# FeignClient returning null

Tags: spring-boot, client, feign

been trying to access my REST api with OpenFeign client. It should return String but all I get is NULL. Tried every possible solution but nothing worked.

My POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>feignclient</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>feignclient</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.RC2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.netflix.eureka</groupId>
            <artifactId>eureka-client</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

Then my main class plus class that FeignClient dependency gets injected too:

```
package com.example.feignclient;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;



@SpringBootApplication
public class FeignclientApplication {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FeignclientApplication.class, args);

        //System.out.println(strAppNameClient.getAppName());
        feignClientObject feignClientObj = new feignClientObject();


    }

}



package com.example.feignclient;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;


public class feignClientObject {

    @Autowired
    StringAppNameClient strAppNameClient;


    public feignClientObject() {
        try {
            System.out.println(strAppNameClient.getAppName());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And the FeignClient class:

```
package com.example.feignclient;

import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;



@FeignClient(name = "SPRING-CLOUD-EUREKA-CLIENT")
public interface StringAppNameClient {

    @GetMapping(value= "/api/AppName")
    String getAppName();
}
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you create `feignClientObject` instance manually `new feignClientObject();`

1. First of all, you have to add annotation [@EnableFeignClients](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html#netflix-feign-starter) to the `FeignclientApplication` class
2. Add [@Component or @Service](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection) to `FeignClientObject` class

If you want to directly get the bean from the [IOC](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html), then:

```java
 ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(FeignclientApplication.class, args);

 feignClientObject client = context.getBean(feignClientObject.class);
```

P.S. also please have a look at [java class name convention](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html): 
`feignClientObject` to `FeignClientObject`

Answer (score 0):

Feign Client needs to be enabled.

```
 @EnableFeignClients(basePackages = {"com.example.feignclient"}) // Required
 @SpringBootApplication
 public class FeignclientApplication {
 .....
```

An object of the class `StringAppNameClient` can be consumed through `@Autowire`.

```
 @Autowire
 private StringAppNameClient stringAppNameClient;
```

Then invoke

```
 stringAppNameClient.getAppName();
```